# How do I upload files in a custom form?

Tags: quickform

`civix generate:form` creates a basic form with a `buildQuickForm()` and `postProcess()` demonstrating a select option.

I want the form to upload a file and save it to a custom field.

If I add: `$this->add('file', 'file_id', "My document")` then I get a normal file upload element on the form, but the problem is what to do with it in the postProcess.

`$this->controller->exportValues()` does not include my `file_id` although it is listed in `$this->getSubmitValues(TRUE)` with the the original file name and tmp_name.

I understand QuickForm does some filtering of submitted values but how do I stop the file details being filtered out and get it saved as a custom field?

Answer (score 4):

I just created a custom extension that uploads a  CSV file and reads it into a table.

I added the file element in `buildQuickForm` as follows

```
  $this->add('File', 'uploadFile', ts('Import Data File'), 'size=30 maxlength=255', TRUE);
```

And the processing of the file was is done  with

```
public function preProcess()
{
    if (isset($this->_submitFiles['uploadFile'])) {
        $uploadFile = $this->_submitFiles['uploadFile'];
        $importer = new CRM_Importer();
        $importer ->truncate();
        $importer -> importCVStoTable($uploadFile['tmp_name']);
    }
}
```

I think the key element is `$this->_submitFiles` and you already found about the `tmp_name`